# What does all uppercase letters mean?

Tags: lambda-calculus

I am reading https://www.irif.fr/~mellies/mpri/mpri-ens/biblio/Selinger-Lambda-Calculus-Notes.pdf and would like to know, what the following statement means:

```
Lambda terms: M,N ::= x | (M N) | (λx.M).
```

It is from page 11.

What does for example mean? Is `x` a type of `M` and `N`?

Comment: They are metavariables (variables in the language of math). They stand for arbitrary  lambda terms. This is distinct from `x` which is an object variable and part of the syntax of the language we're defining.

Comment: So `x` is a part of `M` and `N`? Please explain with an example. I am absolute beginner

Comment: `M` stands for a chunk of syntax. Any chunk of syntax that we can build up with these operators. `x` is a particular piece of syntax so `M` could stand for `x` certainly. It could stand for `(x x) x` as well. Or `\x. x x`.

Comment: The important thing is that `x` is the *syntax for variables in the language we're defining*. `M` is a variable that ranges over a piece of syntax.

Comment: That it means, `M` can be  `\x. x`?

Comment: Yep absolutely. `M` can be anything built up from the operators variables application and abstraction.

Answer (score 5):

As it's explained in the comments, $M$ and $N$ are know as **metavariables**. More importantly, this kind of definition is known as an **inductive definition**, that is, you start with very basic elements (symbols belonging to the set $\mathcal{V}$) and build up more complex things from there.

For instance, let $\mathcal{V} = \{v_0, v_1, \ldots, v_{1001}, \ldots\}$. In the BNF definition:

$$ M,N ::= x \mid (M N) \mid (\lambda x.M) $$

- $x$ can be any of the $\{v_0, v_1, v_2, \ldots \}$. That means any symbol from $\mathcal{V}$ can be considered a $\lambda$-term, a most basic of rules.
- $M$, $N$ are structures already known to be $\lambda$-terms, so from the previous example we can build expressions like $(v_0 ~ v_1)$, $(v_{100} ~ (v_{0} ~ v_{1}))$, $((v_{100} ~ (v_{0} ~ v_{1})) ~ v_2) $ and so on.
- With the previous two rules you can now build more complex expressions like $(\lambda v_{100}. (v_0 ~ v_1))$, since all previous terms made by combining the two previous rules are known to be $\lambda$-terms.
- Now you can mix all three rules, like in $(v_0 ~ (\lambda v_9.(v_9 ~ v_{999})))$